# Failing to implement both NLTK and matplotlib in Python 3.6

Tags: python, matplotlib, nltk

So I'm writing my undergraduate dissertation in corpus linguistics and need to create a corpus from the texts I gathered. I managed to make the corpus just fine with NLTK in Python 3.6, and to play around with it, I tried to implement one of the sample codes in the NLTK manual:

```
>>> cfd = nltk.ConditionalFreqDist(
...           (target, fileid[:4])
...           for fileid in inaugural.fileids()
...           for w in inaugural.words(fileid)
...           for target in ['america', 'citizen']
...           if w.lower().startswith(target))
>>> cfd.plot()
```

I installed matplotlib with pip but it gave me an error message which I didn't understand:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\marcell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-pack
ages\nltk\probability.py", line 1862, in plot
    pylab.legend(loc=legend_loc)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'legend_loc' referenced before assignment
```

I don't know what I did wrong, I have barely any experience in python or programming for that matter. Can anyone help me please?

Some of the lines in *probability.py* per request of Terry Jan Reedy from line 1849 to 1869:

```
for condition in conditions:
        if cumulative:
            freqs = list(self[condition]._cumulative_frequencies(samples))
            ylabel = "Cumulative Counts"
            legend_loc = 'lower right'
        else:
            freqs = [self[condition][sample] for sample in samples]
            ylabel = "Counts"
            legend_loc = 'upper right'
        # percents = [f * 100 for f in freqs] only in ConditionalProbDist?
        kwargs['label'] = "%s" % condition
        pylab.plot(freqs, *args, **kwargs)

    pylab.legend(loc=legend_loc)
    pylab.grid(True, color="silver")
    pylab.xticks(range(len(samples)), [text_type(s) for s in samples], rotation=90)
    if title:
        pylab.title(title)
    pylab.xlabel("Samples")
    pylab.ylabel(ylabel)
    pylab.show()
```

Comment: Since the exception is raised in nltk (not matplotlib), it is not immediately obvious that you did anything wrong, or if so, what.  The nltk code may just be buggy.  Showing some of the code before line 1862 might help.

Comment: Edited, added lines 1849 to 1862.

Comment: I guess you can run into this problem if the call to `nltk.ConditionalFreqDist` failed to produce any reasonable output. Now this is hard to check, because we do not have your data. You may try `print(cfd.keys())` and see if this returns an empty set or dictionary.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Where would I have to try `print(cfd.keys())`? Where do I have to type that in?

Comment: in the window where you typed the rest of your code.